# How to group by week without chunking (query _trailing_ 4 weeks)

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, group-by

I've got a database of jobs which I'd like to count by week for the past month. My current query executes, but it chunks by calendar week instead of the trailing week which is what I want:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', scheduled_for::date) AS weekly,
   COUNT(*)           
FROM jobs_job WHERE state = 'complete' AND scheduled_for > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 month' 
GROUP BY weekly
ORDER BY weekly;
```

How can I change this so that each "weekly" period is exactly 7 days?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want use [**extract week**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

```
SELECT EXTRACT(isoyear FROM scheduled_for) as yearly,
       EXTRACT(WEEK FROM scheduled_for) as weekly,
       COUNT (*)
FROM jobs_job WHERE state = 'complete' AND scheduled_for > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 month' 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(isoyear FROM scheduled_for),
         EXTRACT(WEEK FROM scheduled_for)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(isoyear FROM scheduled_for),
         EXTRACT(WEEK FROM scheduled_for);
```

Comment: Typically **only** the week isn't that sensible. I usually combine that with `extract(isoyear from current_date)` - to prepare for queries that return values from two years

Comment: Thanks! And good catch @a_horse_with_no_name! I tried running this but the EXTRACT command didn't seem to be recognized.. We're definitely running Postgres (we use Redash as a client) but it doesn't recognize the command. Perhaps we are running a different version of Postgres? My mentor isn't SQL knowledgeable and I couldn't turn up any Google searches related to this. If anybody knows what could be wrong, let me know!

Comment: @whrobbins: if you are running Postgres, then `extract(isoyear from ...)` **will** work. What does `select version();` give you?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `select version();` gives me: `PostgreSQL 9.6.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 9.6.8-1.pgdg14.04+1), compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4, 64-bit`. When I run the query I get `Error running query: syntax error at or near "as" LINE 11: GROUP BY EXTRACT (isoyear FROM scheduled_for) as yearly, ^` which refers to the `GROUP BY` line. I tried casting `scheduled_for` to a `date` but that didn't help.. In Redash, the `extract` keyword says "local" instead of "keyword" which concerns me.

Comment: That's not the syntax used in the answer. You can't give an expression in the `group by` an alias via `as`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes my bad I copy paste from the field code. Check again

Comment: It worked! Thank you OP and @a_horse_with_no_name. Learned a lot by trying to figure these out :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the date diff in days and then to divide by 7 to define the weeks.  That would be:

```
SELECT scheduled_for::date + floor((current_date - scheduled_for::date) / 7) * interval '1 week' AS weekly,
       COUNT(*)           
FROM jobs_job WHERE state = 'complete' AND scheduled_for > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 month' 
GROUP BY weekly
ORDER BY weekly;
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran this and it appears to not group as I'd expect. I asked my intern manager but he doesn't quite have the SQL experience to understand this. It seems that the grouping fails. (We round dates to the nearest 15 minute increment). [link to a screenshot](https://ibb.co/cuGRzo)

Comment: @whrobbins . . . There was a typo in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Good catch with the `::date` add-on. I tried running it and got this result: https://ibb.co/dAV5aT. Each day should only have a handful of elements to count, but it's doing something weird. It doesn't look like it's a rolilng sum from each date either, since the changes between `count` are big. Let me know if you have any ideas — I'm stumped..

Comment: would help a lot if you include some sample data and expected output. right now we are just guessing and is frustrating when you said doesnt work on your side and expected we fixed when dont give us all the information.